# Trying to capture a particular pattern with regular expressions (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

The pattern I'm trying to capture is along the lines of:

```
Coin: gp (3840)
```

"gp" can be replaced with "cp", "sp", or "pp", and there can be any string of digits inside the parentheses. The pattern I came up with is:

```
"Coin: 'cp|sp|gp|pp' \(\d+\)"
```

However, this is my result when I try to get a match:

```
>>> print(re.match("Coin: 'cp|sp|gp|pp' \(\d+\)", "Coin: gp (3840)"))
None
```

Which part of the pattern am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pattern matching different options wrong: `'cp|sp|gp|pp'` It's trying to match the literal character `'`.

Your regex should really be something like:

```
>>> re.match("Coin: (?:cp|sp|gp|pp) \(\d+\)", "Coin: gp (3840)")
```

The expression `(?:cp|sp|gp|pp)` creates a non-capturing group of your options.